# Open local files (movies,etc) with predefined app in Mac

Tags: html, macos, hyperlink

I´m developing a little app based on CSS3 and HTML for my own use that contains all my movies collection. When I press the movie poster, it opens the movie file using a regular html link code

[image]

The problem is that Firefox (and other browsers) only lets me save the file (it will download the movie that I already have in my HD), as you can see in the following image.

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dWEz.jpg)

I´m wondering if it´s possíble to open the file automatically with an app installed (in this case with VLC) or run an app with a regular HTML hyperlink.